# AttributeError at /map creating folium map in Django

Tags: python, django, folium

I am reading gps coordinates from a postgressql database, and I am using folium to create a map. I use iframe to embed the map in index.html. The data is being read and displayed in index.html, but the embedded map.html throws an error saying ''QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Lat'' - but my recordset does have a field called Lat and I use it in index.html

I am displaying the data (latitude, longitude, a picture taken at those coordinates) in index.html. I've created a model and have data in a postgressql database. I created a function in views.py where I'm looping through the dataset to create markers in a folium map. Then I'm using iframe to embed it in an index.html

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import PhotoInfo
import folium

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    VarPhotoInfo = PhotoInfo.objects.order_by('DateTaken')

    context = {'PhotoInfo': VarPhotoInfo }

    return render(request,'natureapp/index.html',context)

def show_map(request):
    #creation of map comes here + business logic
    PhotoInfo1 = PhotoInfo.objects.order_by('DateTaken')
    m = folium.Map([33.571345, -117.763265], zoom_start=10)
    test = folium.Html('<b>Hello world</b>', script=True)
    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.RegularPolygonMarker(location=[33.571345, -117.763265], popup=popup).add_to(m)
    fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name = "MyMap")
    for lt, ln, el, fn  in zip(PhotoInfo1.Lat,PhotoInfo1.Lon, PhotoInfo1.DateTaken, PhotoInfo1.PhotoName):
        fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location={float(lt),float(ln)},popup = str(el) +' file: '+fn, icon = folium.Icon(color='green')))

    m.add_child(fg)
    str = m.get_root().render()
    context = {'MyMap': str}

    return render(request, 'natureapp/map.html', context)

map.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NatureMapper</title>
      </head>
<h1>Map goes here </h1>
{{ my_map  }}
</html>

index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NatureMapper</title>
      </head>
<h1>Here it is! </h1>
 {% if PhotoInfo %}

  {% for Photo in PhotoInfo %}

 <p>there is info.</p>
   <p> {{ Photo.PhotoName }}</p>
   <p> {{ Photo.Lat }}</p>
   <p> {{ Photo.Long }}</p>
   <p>  <img src="{{ Photo.PhotoImage.url }}" width = "240" alt=""></p>


  {% endfor %}

 {% else %}

 <p>there is no info.</p>
 {% endif %}

 <iframe id="encoder_iframe" height=95% width="70%" src="{% url 'show_map' %}">
     </iframe>

</html>
```

Index.html displays all the data including the picture fine. 
`show_map` has the following error message:

> AttributeError at /map 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Lat'
>   Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/map Django
>   Version:  2.2 Exception Type: AttributeError Exception Value: 
>   'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Lat' Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\denjs\Documents\DjangoProjects\NatureMapper2\naturemapper2\natureapp\views.py
>   in show_map, line 22 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.7.2 Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\denjs\Documents\DjangoProjects\NatureMapper2\naturemapper2',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\python37.zip',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\lib',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv', 
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\Users\denjs\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\mydjangoenv\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
>   Server time:  Tue, 16 Jul 2019 01:40:33 +0000

Answer (score 0):

A queryset is a list of objects. The queryset does not have the `Lat` attribute attached to it.

In the `index.html` you iterate over a queryset of `PhotoInfo` objects which do have the `Lat` attribute.

```
{% for Photo in PhotoInfo %}
   <p> {{ Photo.Lat }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Where in the `def show_map(request)` view you are not iterating over a queryset and instead are trying to access the `Lat` attribute on a queryset.

```
PhotoInfo1 = PhotoInfo.objects.order_by('DateTaken')
# PhotoInfo1 is not a single object, but rather a list of objects
```

Either change the queryset in `def show_map(request)` to return only a single instance:

```
PhotoInfo1 = PhotoInfo.objects.get(id=1)
```

Or iterate over the `PhotoInfo1` queryset like you did in the template.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, am I iterating in views.py?

Comment: In this line: `for lt, ln, el, fn  in zip(PhotoInfo1.Lat,PhotoInfo1.Lon, PhotoInfo1.DateTaken, PhotoInfo1.PhotoName):` `PhotoInfo1` here is a queryset and `Lat` is not available. If you want to access `Lat` you need a single object.